# Tem uma forma melhor de formatar valor com espaço depois do simbolo da moeda?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Bom dia !

Estou com uma necessidade de formatar o valor com um espaço depois do simbolo da moeda no **Oracle**, eu consegui usando da forma abaixo:

```
select to_char('0','L')||' '||ltrim(to_char('1235675430,12','999G999G999G999G999G990D99') ) from dual;
```

Existe uma forma melhor de fazer, em vez de fazer dessa forma que fiz ?

Answer (score 2):

Fiz da seguinte forma, utilizando o **FM** para tirar os espaços:

```
SELECT 'R$ '||to_char('1235675430,12','FM999G999G999G999D99') FROM DUAL;
```